# set all check boxes inside page to false

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox

I could have any number of checkboxes in my table.

`<input type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("MapID") %>' class="chk" runat="server"/>`...

So how do I set all the checkboxes to false from code behind?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="AccesUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:ListView ID="lvCurrentMaps" runat="server"  >
            <LayoutTemplate>


                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display rndCorner2" id="example" width="100%">
                 <thead>
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" class="itemTableHeader">
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Select" />
                        </td>
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMapID" Text="Map ID" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
               </tbody>
                </table>


            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" class="itemTableData">
                    <td id="Td6" runat="server"  class="chkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("MapID") %>' class="chk" runat="server"/>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server" onclick='<%#"doPostBackForView("+Eval("MapID")+")" %>' style="cursor:pointer !important">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIDMapValue" Text= '<%#Eval("MapID") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" class="altItemTableData">
                    <td id="Td6" runat="server"  class="chkbox">
                        <input id="Checkbox" type="checkbox" value='<%#Eval("MapID") %>' class="chk" runat="server"/>
                    </td>
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server" onclick='<%#"doPostBackForView("+Eval("MapID")+")" %>' style="cursor:pointer !important">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIDMapValue" Text= '<%#Eval("MapID") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td id="Td8" runat="server" onclick='<%#"doPostBackForView("+Eval("MapID")+")" %>' style="cursor:pointer !important">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMapNameValue" Text= '<%#Eval("MapName") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td id="Td9" runat="server" onclick='<%#"doPostBackForView("+Eval("MapID")+")" %>' style="cursor:pointer !important">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMapDescValue" Text= '<%#Eval("MapDesc") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>                   
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I was trying something like:

```
foreach(var li in lvCurrentMaps.Items)
        {
            li.DataItem = false;
        }

        AccesUpdatePanel.Update();
```

any ideas?
possibly through a ScriptManager?

Comment: @John, are you trying to update the CheckBox status in Javascript or backend?

Comment: not in my script though, do I need to? lvCurrentMaps is that name of the listView....trying to update from back end

Comment: sorry! I thought you are trying javascript

Answer (score 0):

Jquery solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chk').prop('checked', false);
});
</script>
```

Comment: is it possible to add this to a script which is run from code behind?

Comment: I have edited the script. put total code in your source code. it will run as soon as document loaded in client side (but not from back end).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<input type="checkbox" Checked='<%# Eval("MapID") %> class="chk" runat="server"/>
```

If the value of data column MapID is not a Boolean, try this

Create a method

```
public bool CheckMapID(object mapID)
{
  if (mapID == null)
  {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and replace the HTML/ASPX code with this

```
<input type="checkbox" Checked=<%# CheckMapID(Eval("MapID")) %> class="chk" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: this throws Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: What kind of value you have inside the column MapID? Isn't it Boolean?